# How can I disable the bell icon/emoji from the title bar in iTerm2?

Tags: command-line, iterm

I find it annoying and get no use from it. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ignoring it?

Comment: @John Don't judge me.

Answer (score 5):

The bell is a visual indicator that the terminal bell "rang".
You can disable it on a profile-by-profile basis in the "Preferences" pane.
Menu: Profiles | Open Profiles | Edit Profiles... | Terminal
in the "Notifications" section uncheck "Show bell icon in tabs"

Comment: This option appears to be for a different greyed-out icon that appears in Tab bars, not for the icon on the Window title bar. Try it out.

Comment: I tried it before writing the answer. You can check it on the fly by using the "edit session..." contextual menu (right-click on the iterm2 window) and going in the "terminal" pane. It works for me.

Comment: I have the version 3.1.5

Comment: I don't get it, if the bell rings (I guess meaning ^G was sent to the terminal) does the icon stay there forever? That doesn't seem to make sense. There must be some ad hoc way to clear it without disabling it for future rings. No?

Answer (score 2):

This is behavior is controlled via the **Show bell icon in tabs** preference mentioned earlier, but if changing that setting doesn't appear to do anything, you may have a corrupt preferences file or cache. Please try the following:

1. quit **Iterm2**
2. open Apple's **Terminal** (in /Applications/Utilities)
3. **delete** the following two items: `~/Library/Caches/com.googlecode.iterm2`& `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist*`
4. re-launch **Iterm2**
5. re-disable **Show bell icon in tabs** in **Preferences** > **Profile** > **Terminal**

Re-test to determine if issue is resolved.